# typescript how to simplify React.componentPropsWithoutRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

here is my code:

```
// impl GetProps<"html-element"> like GetProps<"div">
export type GetProps<T extends ElementType> = ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>

// impl GetProps<Component>
export type GetProps2<T extends Component> = ComponentPropsWithoutRef<new () => T>
```

I expect merge GetProps and GetProps2 into one GetProps, and make support syntax `GetProps<Component>` and `GetProps<"div">`, how to do?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you just need to create [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```js
import { Component, ComponentPropsWithoutRef, ElementType } from 'react'

// impl GetProps<"html-element"> like GetProps<"div">
export type GetProps<T extends ElementType> = ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>

// impl GetProps<Component>
export type GetProps2<T extends Component> = ComponentPropsWithoutRef<new () => T>

type Result<T extends ElementType | Component> =
    (T extends ElementType
        ? ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>
        : (T extends Component
            ? ComponentPropsWithoutRef<new () => T>
            : never)
    )

type Test = Result<'div'>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wX2zkm)

Answer (score 0):

I find simple solution, use ts conditional type `?type:type2`, see following code

```
// @ts-ignore ComponentPropsWithoutRef<new () => T> in webstorm is raised syntax err but in typescript compile and runtime it work
export type GetProps<T extends ElementType | Component> = T extends ElementType ? ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T> : ComponentPropsWithoutRef<new () => T> // `new () => T` means `typeof T`
```